# Official tensorflow tutorial: Input pipeline in retraining using transfer learning (retrain.py)

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-recognition, pre-trained-model

I want to use transfer learning with Google's Inception network for an image recognition problem. I am using retrain.py from the TensorFlow example source for inspiration and follow [this official tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) from Google.

However, its input pipeline  is "each step chooses 10 images (10 is batch_size) at random from the training set, finds their bottlenecks from the cache, and feeds them into the final layer to get predictions."

Specifically, in its code [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) 
, batch_size images will be retrieved by selecting randomly each images. For each image, find its image index by

```
image_index = random.randrange(MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS + 1)
```

where `MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS` = 2^27 + 1, then `image_index` will be moduloed by the available number of images for the label.

My questions are:

1) Why it has to create batches like that (random to a large number and then mod the length of each class)? Why don't we just random to the length of each class)

2) If we choose a random set of images for each time of feeding, do we miss a large portion of data and receive duplicated feed examples? Why is the input pipeline arranged as normal: we have many epochs, each epoch is full data and is divided into many batches, then we feed each batch to our model?

Thank you very much!!

**Reference**

in retrain.py, `train_bottlenecks`, `train_ground_truth` (these are fed into model) are created by `get_random_distorted_bottlenecks`. In this function, we loop for each images until we have enough batch_size images: find a random label, then find the random index:

```
label_index = random.randrange(class_count)
label_name = list(image_lists.keys())[label_index]
image_index = random.randrange(MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS + 1)
```